# Может ли команда запаздывать?

Tags: android, java

Не понимаю. В моей главной активности есть сей момент:

```
    gvMain = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gvMain);
    gvMain.setNumColumns(4);
    gvMain.setHorizontalSpacing(10);
    gvMain.setVerticalSpacing(10);
    ...
    ResizeDefaultBackgrounds();
    new UpdateTask(this).execute(dataTime);
```

т.е. я устанавливаю в GridView 4 колонки, а позже выполняю ресайз фонов (т.к. заведомо не известно на экране с каким разрешением будет приложение, а деформировать фоны не хорошо, поэтому обрезаю). Так вот, в методе ResizeDefaultBackgrounds() есть строка

```
    int picSize = getSizeBitmapToDisplay(0.95f);
```

Где в свою очередь getSizeBitmapToDisplay использует количество колонок:

```
    int count = gvMain.getNumColumns();
    DisplayMetrics metricsB = ((MainActivity)context).getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int newWidth = (int)((metricsB.widthPixels/(float)count)*fillPart);
    return  newWidth;
```

дабы не хранить неоправданно большие картинки, так сказать. Так вот если вывести в логи значение gvMain.getNumColumns(); из последнего отрывка, то он будет равняться -1. Как так? Я же задал 4? При этом если использовать

```
int picSize = getSizeBitmapToDisplay(0.95f);
```

внутри следующей команды из главной активности

```
new UpdateTask(this).execute(dataTime);
```

То там уже корректно будет геттер давать 4 колонки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в onCreate этот метод используете? Попробуйте ViewTreeObserver:

```
        ViewTreeObserver vto = gvMain.getViewTreeObserver();  
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {  
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override  
            public void onGlobalLayout() {  
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) 
                    v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
                else
                    v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                //здесь gvMain.getNumColumns() точно вернёт 4

            }  
        });
```

Comment: Да, в onCreate. Т.е. странно выходит. Сперва задаю 4 колонки, после этого вызываю метод, внутри которого метод, внутри которого запрашиваю количество и получаю -1. Мистика. Ведь ПОСЛЕ же вызвал того как задал. С классом ViewTreeObserver дела пока не имел, скорее всего просто в ресурсы придется положить количество колонок...

Comment: @Saint потому что ваши изменения в onCreate вступят в силу уже после прорисовки элемента. Хотя, попробуйте requestLayout(); вызвать для gvMain после внесения изменений

Comment: почему мистика - все логично. Пока с метода onCreate не выйдите, все элементы хотя и созданы, но ещё не нарисованы. Поэтому, они ещё не знают своих размеров и прочих характеристик, которые рассчитываются во время отрисовки. Видимо методы setNumColumns/getNumColumns такие же.

Comment: Спасибо, только первые шаги делаю, не знал такой момент.